# Estoy intentando crear un lite server en webpack, y para ello instalé dependencia de node usando npm install. Al poner npm start esto fue lo q salio

Tags: webpack

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (C:\Users\Larguirucho\Documents\ts-intro\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\Larguirucho\Documents\ts-intro\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at handleParseError (C:\Users\Larguirucho\Documents\ts-intro\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
at C:\Users\Larguirucho\Documents\ts-intro\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
at C:\Users\Larguirucho\Documents\ts-intro\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
at C:\Users\Larguirucho\Documents\ts-intro\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Larguirucho\Documents\ts-intro\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Larguirucho\Documents\ts-intro\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4) {
```

opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Comment: Al instalar las dependencias de node me salieron varias advertencias sobre librerias que estaban obsoletas (deprecated)